# nodemon starting infinite .node-xmlhttprequest-sync files

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I have an app that imports a module that has a promise.

It works fine when I launch it with "node app.js"

However, when I launch "nodemon" it keeps creating files .node-xmlhttprequest-sync-1516 (random numbers in the end)

Anyone has encountered this issue before? Can't find any answer on google... thanks a lot !

```
nodemon
[nodemon] 1.17.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
app running on port 3100
app running on port 8080
secs:38.409
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
app running on port 3100
app running on port 8080
secs:0.615
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
app running on port 3100
app running on port 8080
secs:0.661
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
app running on port 3100
app running on port 8080
secs:0.593
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
app running on port 3100
app running on port 8080
secs:0.59
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
app running on port 3100
app running on port 8080
secs:0.603
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
app running on port 3100
app running on port 8080
secs:0.597
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Comment: if i don't stop it, it keeps creating those files infinitely. Also, i have to delete them manually after I end the batch job....

Comment: You probably need to ignore a file type/folder. There is probably something getting written while the server is running and it is causing nodemon to restart on you.

Answer (score 1):

You are watching for changes on `*.*`. Your server is probably writing a file at some point and it is causing the server to restart and this is happening over and over. Check out the [docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files) on how to ignore certain files/folders

Comment: i usually use a nodemon config file with a list of ignored files/dirs, but you can also add a section to your package.json, or pass arguments on the command line - https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files

Comment: thanks guys ! I will try to find the techniques to setup ignores

Comment: If my answer helped/solved your problem please select my answer as the accepted answer. Read more here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235