# Connect app engine with ibm cloudant using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest, cloudant

I am using a standard app engine configuration in Node.js. I am having trouble accessing ibm cloudant from app engine using the xmlhttprequest.

The code i am using for the request from App engine is as follows:

```
var getAllDocuments = function(database, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","<link>" + database + "/_all_docs?include_docs=true", false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", myauthenticateUser(userName, passWord));
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
         callback(data, xhr.status);
        }
        else{
            callback(null, xhr.status);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

when the above code is executed the following error happens-:  Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-11 '.

FYI: I am not saving any temp file in my app engine.

Is there something to be added to the yaml file that i created or is this something else?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems self-explanatory:

> Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open `.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-11`

Those files are genetared due to the usage of syncronous requests. Please take a look into this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773882/nodemon-starting-infinite-node-xmlhttprequest-sync-files)  where they launch "nodemon" it keeps creating files `.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-1516` (random numbers in the end).

Additionally, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) I found that:

> Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), Blink 39.0, and Edge 13, synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to their negative impact on the user experience.

> Synchronous XHR is now in deprecation state.

So, you might think to restructure your code to use async instead.

I wanted to search more and I found [this entry in github issues](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/703#issuecomment-403171562)

> Generally, if you're getting these files, it means you're using synchronous http requests, which is a no no. You shouldn't do that, for this effects and other reasons. Please check your code for synchronous requests and remove them.

> If you see Truffle code that uses synchronous requests, please let us know.

And I think [this responds to your question](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/1019#issuecomment-403171251):

> Just FYI, this file isn't truffle generated. It comes as a result of using synchronous http requests in node.

SOLUTION: change to asynchronous request. For that you have to change this line

```
xhr.open("GET","<link>" + database + "/_all_docs?include_docs=true", false);
```

for this:

```
xhr.open("GET","<link>" + database + "/_all_docs?include_docs=true", true);
```

Changing the flag `false` to **`true`**. For more details take a look into [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)